# EAGetMail equivalent in ubuntu

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I couldn't find the dll EAGetMail in ubuntu, I'm using c# in monondevelop.

Is there a equivalent dll seperatly for ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I use the open-source MailKit (and MimeKit) for xplat (including mobile support) access to IMAP, POP3, and SMTP.

- http://www.mimekit.net
- https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit
- https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/

Note: I am *NOT* affiliated to the MimeKit/MailKit, just a dev that uses and likes it.

Comment: I used this API, and I get the below error: Unable to find seq points for method '(wrapper managed-to-native) System.Net.Sockets.Socket:Connect_internal (intptr,System.Net.SocketAddress,int&)'.
* Assertion at debugger-agent.c:5496, condition `sp' not met  --- in the step     client.Connect ("pop.gmail.com", 110, false);

Comment: I have not seen a "condition `sp' not met" issue in a long time, not a MailKit specific issue, but a Mono one. Are you running an old version of Mono? If so, try upgrading, otherwise post an issue over on MailKit's github issues and see if they have seen the issue.